# Get-Content : Cannot find path 'H:\System.Management.Automation>InvocationInfo\before.txt' because it does not exist

Tags: powershell, file-get-contents

I'm dynamically creating a simple web page. For some reason, I get the above error message.

This is my code so far.

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value;
    if($Invocation.PSScriptRoot)
    {
        $Invocation.PSScriptRoot;
    }
    Elseif($Invocation.MyCommand.Path)
    {
        Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
    }
    else
    {
        $Invocation.InvocationName.Substring(0,$Invocation.InvocationName.LastIndexOf("\"));
    }
    return $Invocation
}

################################## start here #########################################################################

#write before to html file

$filenameOut = "php_docs_newest.html"
$filenameBegin = "before.txt"
$filenameAfter = "after.txt"

#get filenames from directories and put in group named for folder
#get current working dir
$cwd = Get-ScriptDirectory #(Get-Location).path #PSScriptRoot #(Get-Item -Path ".").FullName
$filenamePathOut = Join-Path $cwd $filenameOut

#beginning html content to file
$filenamePathBeginning = Join-Path $cwd $filenameBegin
Get-Content -Path $filenamePathBeginning | Set-Content -Path $filenamePathOut #this is where I get subject error message
```

When I look at `$cwd`, it's `C:\Users\me\Documents\subdir`, which looks good.

Also, `$filenamePathOut` shows `C:\Users\me\Documents\subdir\php_docs_newest.html`, which is fine also.

I'm not sure why I get an error message that is using `H:\System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo` in it. How do I fix this? Is there a cast or conversion needed?

I was trying to use [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) to do a read/write together.

After this precursory html written to the out file, I will write a dynamic list of files read from a sub-directory.

Comment: That's because you `return $Invocation`

Comment: I'm not used to the concept that I don't need to return a variable from functions.  When I commented out the return statement in the function the error message went away. The $cwd variable content looks the same that is returned as it did before I got rid of the return.

Comment: I see that you had commented out `PSScriptRoot`. Have you tried to use `$PSScriptRoot` with the $ to indicate it's a variable?

Comment: @RichMoss - Mathias's suggestion was the answer, because I had returned the variable, and not the result, from GetScriptDirectory.  I had a bunch commented out on the PSScriptRoot line in the main part of the code, but once I removed the return, it was working.

Comment: Cool - glad that worked for you :) My point was that the $PSScriptRoot [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6) would make your script a bit simpler.